# django .- Este template y otro no muestran imagenes

Tags: django, imagen

```
  Aqui muestro  mi modelo

## Model -----------
class Cliente(models.Model):
    
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.logo.name)

        
    def ruta_logo(instance, filename):
        return f"photos/{instance.user.id}/{filename}"

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    giro = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to= ruta_logo, blank=True, null=True)
    loc = models.CharField(max_length = 80, null=True, blank=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    contacto = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
```

Esta es la URL principal

```
# Url principal -------------
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('forms.urls')),
    path('esgrima/', include('esgrima.urls')),
    path('eventos/',include('eventos.urls')),
    path('merca/', include('merca.urls')),
    path('cuenta/', include('cuenta.urls')),
    
] 
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Aqui la URL del proceso
#--------------------

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from cuenta.views import Login, Logout, register, prod_list, prod_agregar, prod_edit,prod_borrar, modi_register, miempresa_edit, iglesia
from cuenta.views import micuenta, cuenta, password_reset_request, maps, logotipo, maps, mapanuevo,           pagos2, iglesia_add, iglesia_editar
from cuenta.views import iglesia_sel, iglesia_buscar


urlpatterns = [
    path('', cuenta, name='cuenta'),
    path('miempresa_edit/', miempresa_edit, name='miempresa_edit'),
    path('micuenta/', micuenta, name='micuenta'),
]
```

Settings.py

```
# -------------
from pathlib import Path
import smtplib 
import os 

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
with open('rat.txt', mode='r') as archivo:
    line = archivo.readline()
    cont = 0
    while line:
        #print("Line {}: {}".format(cont, line.strip()))
        if cont == 0:
            SECRET_KEY = line
        if cont == 1:
            PATH_CHAT = line
        line = archivo.readline()
        cont += 1
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_countries',
    'forms',
    'esgrima',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'merca',
    'eventos',
    'crispy_forms',
    'cuenta',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django_google_maps', 
    #'rest_framework',
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig', 
    ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST=True
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mundo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                #'django.core.context_processors.request'

            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mundo.wsgi.application'
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    #{
    #    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    #},
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-mx'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static/")]

MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.cookie.CookieStorage'
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.file"


CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': 'c:/django/project/mundo/var/tmp/django_cache',
        #'LOCATION': MEDIA_URL.join('/var/tmp/django_cache'),
        'TIMEOUT': 60,
        'OPTIONS': {
        'MAX_ENTRIES': 1000
        }
    }
}

# Vista ------
@ login_required
def prod_edit(request, id):
    prod = Prod.objects.get(id=id)
    if prod.user != request.user: # Proceso para no modificar registros ajenos
        messages.warning(request,"Error")
        return redirect('prod_list')
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ProdForm(instance=prod)
    else:
        form = ProdForm(request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=prod)
        ##  Checar que el producto corresponda al usuario
                
        if form.is_valid():
            #form.save()
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
        
            #----------------------------------compactar imagen
            # id= request.session['id_photo']
            prod=Prod.objects.get(id=id)
            long = prod.avatar
            if not long:
                messages.success(request, "No hay imagen")
                return redirect('prod_list')
            compactar(request,real_path_mas_nom)
            if False:
                #prod=Prod.objects.get(id=id)
                prod.delete() 
            return redirect ('prod_list')
        
        else:
            messages.success(request, "Error en su información. Corrija")
    
     return render(request, 'cuenta/prod_edit.html', {'form':form})
```

Codigo HTML . Antes del formulario hay otro codigo para desplegar mensajes de error y cosas asi. Ya lo he eliminado para ver si eso era el problema, pero no hay cambios

```
##HTML  miempresa.html  HTML
<form action= "/cuenta/miempresa_edit/"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"/> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div align="left">
       <div class="col-md-5">
          {% if form.logo %}
             {% for object in object_list.all %}
                 <img src="{{ form.logo.url }}" alt="Imagen">
             {% endfor %}
             <img src="{{ form.logo.url }} "  width = "100px" alt="{{form.logo.url}}" /> </img>
             <!--Estas dos lineas de imagenes no despliegan nada -->
         {% else %}
             <img src="static/camara.png" width = "50px"/> </img></td>
             <!--Esta linea si despliega imagen estática, pero el sistema si encuentra                                                          
             {{form.logo}} pero no {{form.logo.url}}  -->
         {% endif %}
         <p>Nombre de Empresa........ {{ form.nombre }} </p>
         <p> Nombre de contacto........ {{ form.contacto }} </p>
         <button type="submit"> Guardar </button>
</form> 
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'cuenta' %}">Salir</a>
```

Tengo otros procesos donde si se muestran imagenes pero en este último no muestra imagen. Si en el navegador  le pongo que inspeccione el elemento y despliega :   como si no existiera la variable {{form.logo.url}}
He intentado varias opciones pero nada da resultados. Espero puedan orientarme. Considero que settings.py esta bien configurado, pero muestro todo el código. En el template se muestra el valor de form.logo  pero cuando pido que despliegue la imagen no muestra nada

---

Dicho en otras palabras, cuando envío en formulario instanciado para poder actualizar un registro, no me permite desplegar la imagen.  Pero cuando solo leo el registro, puedo desplegar la imagen. Alguien sabe ¿porque?

Comment: ¿Si muestras el código de la web en el navegador, qué te está mostrando como ruta de la imagen?

Comment: GRacias.   Muestra la misma linea  <p><img src width = "50px" alt="{{form.logo.url}}" /> </img></p>

Comment: La linea debería ser asi  <p><img src = " {{ form.logo.url }} "  width = "50px" alt="{{form.logo.url}}" /> </img></p>

Comment: Es decir, desaparece en los 3 navegadores que tengo todo esto = " {{ form.logo.url }} "   . Es decir cuando le pongo que inspeccione el elemento.   Eso me sucede en Edge, Opera y Mozilla

Comment: No muestra la imagen cuando quiero desplegarla , pero cuando accesas el nombre de la imagen para modificarla, si se despliega correctamente.

Comment: Después de un mes, pude encontrar la solución.----   form = Logo(instance=cliente)    --->> aqui es formulario en blanco               y  cliente=Cliente.objects.get(user=request.user)  de aqui puedo obtener el logo el cual si se despliega  . No entiendo la razón. Espero alguien pueda explicarme.

Comment: Gracias a todos